# highlight rows in SELENIDE

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, highlight, selenide

I am trying to do this:

```
@Test
    public void tableTest() {
        getDriver().get(BASE_URL + "tabulka.php");
        List<WebElement> rows = getDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//table//tbody//tr"));

        for (WebElement row : rows) {
            if (row.getText().contains("Florian")){
                ((JavascriptExecutor) getDriver()).executeScript("arguments[0].style.border='3px solid red'", row);
            }
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uYAT.png)

But in Selenide

Selenide

```
   @Test
    public void tableTestAi() {
       ElementsCollection rows = $$("#table tbody tr");
        
        for (SelenideElement row : rows) {
            `if (row.getText().contains("Florian")){

                row.shouldHave(Condition.attribute("style", "border: 3px solid red;"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Test passed but nothing happens

And here test with highLight :

```
    @Test
    public void itShouldHaveFloriannm() {
        ElementsCollection rows = $$("#table tbody tr");
        $x("//table//td[text()='Florian']").scrollTo().highlight();

        for (SelenideElement row : rows) {
            if (row.getText().contains("Florian")){
                row.scrollTo().highlight();
            }
        }
    }
```

It highLights only first Florian

```
@Test
     public void testFloriangg() {
        $x("//table//td[text()='Florian']").highlight()
                .findAll(By.xpath("//table//td[text()='Florian']"));
     }
```

It highLights also only first Florian, the others not. I need to hightlight all rows with this name. Where is the problem?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvqFA.png)

I have
Selenide version 7.2.1
Selenium version 4.18.1
JDK 21